# PowerMockito to mock a static method inside a class using MockitoJUnitRunner

Tags: java, static, mockito, powermockito

I want to user PowerMockito inside a test class that has `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`. I do the following static method mocking:

```
BeanLocator mockBeanLocator = mock(BeanLocator.class);
PowerMockito.mockStatic(PortalBeanLocatorUtil.class);
PowerMockito.when(PortalBeanLocatorUtil.getBeanLocator()).thenReturn(mockBeanLocator);
```

The last line does not work. I get this error message:

```
    org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
2. inside when() you do not call method on mock but on some other object.
3. the parent of the mocked class is not public.
   It is a limitation of the mock engine.
```

`PortalBeanLocatorUtil`is a public class with `public static BeanLocator getBeanLocator()`. All of these classes are from third party library. What is the proper way to mock the `getBeanLocator()`static method?

Comment: Fix your class and inject `BeanLocator` instead.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I'm not sure if I follow your suggestion. Which class do you refer to? I can't modify neither BeanLocator nor PortalBeanLocatorUtil

Comment: Instead, try to use `BDDMockito` for stubbing: `BDDMockito.given(PortalBeanLocatorUtil.getBeanLocator()).willReturn(mockBeanLocator);
`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the fact that you are returning a mock as a result of calling another mock. Try using an instance of BeanLocator.